# Overload push_back() for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

In my case I have a `std::list<Ort*>` , where as Ort is a custom class I've made
and the list holds the pointers to the Ort-objects.

I like to overload the `list.push_back()` function using `+=` so that I can
directly push an object by writing :

```
List<Ort*> Orte;
Ort* o = new Ort(..);

Orte+=o;
```

What I tried is :

```
void Navi::operator+=(const Ort& b)
{
    *this->Orte.push_back(b);
}
```

Navi is a class which holds the list 'Orte'.

But it tells me that it can't find the correct operator overload - aka my parameters are incorrect.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you overloaing `Navi` when `Orte` is a `List<Ort*>`?

Comment: Edited - Navi is a class which has an attribute List<Ort*> Orte;

Comment: `const Ort&` and `Ort*` are really different types.

Comment: I tried to do it using the * char and as result I got this :

Comment: navi.cpp:340:20: error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::list<Ort*>' and 'Ort*')

Comment: You need to show some actual code if you want actual help. Specifically, what this `Navi` thing really is. Have a look in the Help Center for the section on writing a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this anyway? Pointless operator overloads, especially for an existing class like `std::list`, will just lead to confusion for anyone else reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the const-ness of the pointer.
If you look here
[Question about const pointer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309206/question-about-const-pointer-in-c)

You will see that changing the argument from const Ort& b to Ort *const b
should fix your problem. (Since you want to push back a const pointer to a List).